# How to install Maven Plugin on RAD?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, ibm-rad

IBM RAD does not support maven out of the box and the first thing any developer do is, to install new software from RAD help menu with m2e eclipse udpate url.

" Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317).
Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.4.0.20130601-0317) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found"

Comment: Please note the description of the "rad"-tag: "Please don't use this tag, it is ambiguous. For IBM Rational Application Developer related questions please use [tag:ibm-rad]" - I've changed that for you.

Comment: Which "m2e eclipse udpate url" is that? Are you letting it search all of the known sites? If so, what sites are known?